# Webpack w/ Babel loader returning empty object

Tags: webpack, babeljs, clojurescript, shadow-cljs

I have a build pipeline that that takes ClojureScript code and transpiles that down to Javascript using Shadow-Cljs. The transpile can export a [npm module](https://shadow-cljs.github.io/docs/UsersGuide.html#target-npm-module) or a [node library](https://shadow-cljs.github.io/docs/UsersGuide.html#target-node-library).

The output is then passed through Webpack with Babel loader to polyfill for the browser.

All together the steps are:
`Shadow-CLIJS(CLJS) -> Webpack(Node Library) -> Web`

The intermediary "Node Library" works fine in a Node.js (see repl output below), but for some reason the Webpack polyfill when imported into a React app loads an empty object.

Not sure how to solve this issue.

**webpack.config.js**

```
  const path = require("path");
  const NodePolyfillPlugin = require("node-polyfill-webpack-plugin");

  const paths = {
    src: path.resolve(__dirname, "../sdk-js/lib/sdk.js"),
    build: path.resolve(__dirname, "./lib"),
  };

  module.exports = {
    entry: paths.src,
    mode: "development",
    devtool: "source-map",
    output: {
      path: paths.build,
      filename: "index.js",
    },
    plugins: [
      new NodePolyfillPlugin(),
    ],
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    resolve: {
      modules: [paths.src, "node_modules"],
      extensions: [".tsx", ".ts", ".js", ".json"],
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.(ts|tsx|js)$/,
          use: {
            loader: "babel-loader",
            options: {
              presets: [
                [
                  "@babel/preset-env",
                  {
                    targets: {
                      esmodules: true,
                    },
                  },
                ],
              ],
            },
          },
        },
      ],
    },
  };
```

**REPL Output for Node Library:**

```
> sdk
{
  v1: {
    init: [Function: Ew] {
      l: [Function (anonymous)],
      g: [Function (anonymous)],
      J: 1
    },
    halt: [Function: halt],
    account: { create: [Function: create] },
    workspace: { available: [Function: available] }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is was a RTM problem. Webpack needs `library` and `libraryTarget` set.

```
output: {
    path: paths.build,
    filename: "index.js",
    library: "sdk",
    libraryTarget: "commonjs2",
  },
```